# How to use async task as a method with parameters

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task, func

I get confused, when tried to use async task. Everything is fine if I use this method without parameters, but when I add parameters to it, it says that cannot convert System.Threading.Tasks.Task to System.Func. So how to use it properly and fix this error?

Main:

```
Timers t = new Timers();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    t.StartTimerTemplate(TEMPLATEupdateSong("test", "test", "test"));//error occurs in this line
}

async Task TEMPLATEupdateSong(string url, string sender, string labelName)
{
    string nowPlaying = await getter.getString(url);
    nowPlaying = XDocument.Parse(nowPlaying).ToString();

    var outputLabel = this.Controls.OfType<Label>()
                      .FirstOrDefault(control => control.Name == labelName);

    outputLabel.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        outputLabel.Text = sender + "\n" + nowPlaying
    ));
}
```

Timers.cs:

```
public void StartTimerTemplate(Func<Task> updateTemplate)
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(50000);
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => timer_Elapsed(sender, e, updateTemplate());
    timer.Start();
}

async void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e, Task task)
{
    await task;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method expects a `Func<Task>`, not a `Task`.

```
 t.StartTimerTemplate(() => TEMPLATEupdateSong("test", "test", "test"));
```

Or

```
t.StartTimerTemplate(async () => await TEMPLATEupdateSong("test", "test", "test"));
```